# Django-CMS: Multiple domains on same project

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-cms

i'm trying to run django-cms on two different domains. For that i created two domains (django.contrib.sites) and added to them django-cms pages.
Now i created a SiteDetectionMiddleware:

```
class SiteDetectionMiddleware:
  def process_request(self, request):
    settings.SITE_ID = 1
    host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST')
    if host:
      try:
        site = Site.objects.get(domain=host)
        settings.SITE_ID = site.id
      except Site.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

It seems to work correctly, when i call the website in browser for the first time after restarting apache. Then i changed to the other site and got a NoReverseMatch Error.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

I thought this should work out of the box in django-cms?

regards Colin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you setting the `SITE_ID` statically? You should probably create two settings files and use some form of inheritance depending on project differentiation, e.g.:

**local_settings.py** (not under version control holds sensitive data like database passwords and the secret key)

```
SECRET_KEY = 'as!sfhagfsA@$1AJFS78787124!897zR81'
```

**settings.py** (holds settings that are equal for both sites)

```
# preferably at the bottom
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

**settings_foo.py** (holds settings specific to site 1)

```
from settings import *

SITE_ID = 1
```

**settings_bar.py** (holds settings specific to site 2)

```
from settings import *

SITE_ID = 2
```

**settings_deployment_foo.py** (overwrites variables for production)

```
from settings_foo import *

DEBUG = False
```

**settings_deployment_bar.py** (overwrites variables for production)

```
from settings_bar import *

DEBUG = False
```

Then just create two sites within `admin/sites` or use a fixture (assuming you are sharing a database cross these projects you'll only have to do this once).

Comment: @Hedde van der Heide how can we load the respective settings.py for each site dynamically based on the typed url.

Comment: @Wirzi how do u load the `settings_foo.py` and `settings_bar.py` dynamically based on site id?

Comment: Use the wsgi.py file to load different settings files for each domain.

Comment: I use multiple VirtualHost in the apache httpd.conf file and load the for example a foo_wsgi.py for one domain and a bar_wsgi.py for the other one.
Live example: https://gourmendo.com and https://blog.gourmendo.com

Comment: more infos about this problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-cms/jQNWVos9vg8

Comment: Better or course will be to use .env file with defined environment variables instead of different files for settings, but idea will be the same, thank you!)

Answer (score 4):

If your languages are same for all domain like `xyz.com` and `abc.com`

So you can handle it in middleware, so middleware can assign the available languages to subdomains at runtime.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class SiteMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(domain=request.get_host())
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            current_site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.DEFAULT_SITE_ID)

        request.current_site = current_site
        settings.SITE_ID = current_site.id
        settings.SITE_NAME = current_site.name
        if settings.SITE_ID is not 1:
            settings.CMS_LANGUAGES[settings.SITE_ID] = settings.CMS_LANGUAGES[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

After few hours trial and error, I got the following solution.

We need to keep relation of the between `SITE` and `CMS_LANGUAGES`

For example, I have two sites `abc.com` with site ID 1 and `xyz.com` with site ID 2

> so you need to mentioned the following relationship in `settings.py`

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
        ## Customize this
        'default': {
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        },
        1: [
            {
                'public': True,
                'code': 'en',
                'hide_untranslated': False,
                'name': gettext('en'),
                'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            },
            {
                'public': True,
                'code': 'zh',
                'hide_untranslated': False,
                'name': gettext('zh'),
                'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            },
            {
                'public': True,
                'code': 'my',
                'hide_untranslated': False,
                'name': gettext('my'),
                'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            },
        ],
        2: [
            {
                'public': True,
                'code': 'en',
                'hide_untranslated': False,
                'name': gettext('en'),
                'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            },
            {
                'public': True,
                'code': 'zh',
                'hide_untranslated': False,
                'name': gettext('zh'),
                'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            },
            {
                'public': True,
                'code': 'my',
                'hide_untranslated': False,
                'name': gettext('my'),
                'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            },
        ],
    }
```

Also I am using the `site` middleware, which detect the site id using domain name.

I hope it helps someone :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you tell me which SITE middleware you have used.